# Hadoop KMS not recommended?

Tags: security, hadoop, cloudera

While reading the: [Cloudera KMS Installation procedure](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_kms_install.html#concept_rcw_j3t_tr), I've found that

> Cloudera strongly recommends not using Java Keystore KMS in production environments.

I couldn't find any arguments behind this recommendations.
Are there any known risks that are fixed with Cloudera implementation (Trustee)?

Answer (score 0):

According to this

> Cloudera provides two implementations of the Hadoop KMS:

and this

> Cloudera strongly recommends not using Java Keystore
>   KMS in production environments.

and this

> Cloudera strongly recommends using Key Trustee KMS in
>   production environments to improve the security, durability, and
>   scalability of your cryptographic key management.

I can do conclusion, that their tech lead dislike Java KeyStore KMS, but, for backward compatibilities, their team still work with both of implementations.